# How could I add list in list in code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I was trying to scrape Instagram and I have already achieved my goal of scraping, but the result I get is perfect but I want it to be stored in the list in a list.

Code:-

```
Post links = ['https://www.instagram.com/p/BesW08pHfUt', 'https://www.instagram.com/p/BQZyTtej4yj']

      for post_link in post_links:
        _ = API.getMediaComments(get_media_id(post_link), max_id = 100)
        for c in reversed(API.LastJson['comments']):
            comment.append(c["user"]["username"])
```

The comments I get from each post links from Instagram

```
'https://www.instagram.com/p/BesW08pHfUt':-  'headhotel', 'famegalore', 'motivationpoem', 'malicioussatan'

'https://www.instagram.com/p/BQZyTtej4yj':- 'monarch_motivation', 'headhotel', 'motivationpoem'
```

The output I get

```
['headhotel', 'famegalore', 'motivationpoem', 'malicioussatan', 'monarch_motivation', 'headhotel', 'motivationpoem']
```

The output I want

```
[['headhotel', 'famegalore', 'motivationpoem', 'malicioussatan'], ['monarch_motivation', 'headhotel', 'motivationpoem']]
```

I know this is kind of easy but I have been coded this scraper in 2 days so I have got a bit of confused!

Comment: We have no idea where the comments nor outputs you mentioned come from.  Your code snippet isn't descriptive enough.

Comment: What does `_ = API.getMediaComments(get_media_id(post_link), max_id = 100)` do?  More precisiely, why are you storing the return value of that call in `_`, and then not using it?

Comment: @PM2Ring It gets the comments from the post link of Instagram

Comment: If you don't need the return value of the call then don't assign it. Just do `API.getMediaComments(get_media_id(post_link), max_id = 100)`.

Comment: That code is needed in further code and it is not related to my question at all

Comment: Does my code do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that API, but I think you want to do something like this:

```
for post_link in post_links:
    _ = API.getMediaComments(get_media_id(post_link), max_id = 100)
    sublist = []
    for c in reversed(API.LastJson['comments']):
        sublist.append(c["user"]["username"])
    comment.append(sublist)
```

That creates a new sublist on each iteration of the outer loop, which the inner loop fills, and then we append the sublist to the main `comment` list.